# Why is the $\langle v_{x}^{2} \rangle=\frac{1}{3} \langle v^2 \rangle$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

For a randomly moving particle. Or, I suppose that 1/3 could generalise to 1/n, where n is the non rotational degrees of freedom for that particle.

Related reference [Kinetic Theory of Gasses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory#Properties).

Comment: I don't believe that this is the case, I can certainly set up states whose expectation value of velocity in a certain direction is zero: $e^{i p x}$ has $\langle v_y \rangle \sim \langle \partial_y \rangle = 0$.

Comment: He may have been using it in a context so that I didn't understand that it was a special case, but Feynman in Chapter 39 of Vol 1 disagrees with you.

Comment: @DJBunk I think this question concerns a statistical average in a large population of particles, not the probabilistic average of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: +1 kinetic theory of gases blew my mind 20 years ago, and you brought it all back with this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding is that this question is being asked in the context of the kinetic theory of classical gases.  In that context, here is the argument:

If the system is rotationally invariant, then we should have $\langle v_x^2 \rangle = \langle v_y^2 \rangle = \langle v_z^2 \rangle$.  Thus $\langle v^2 \rangle = \langle (v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 )\rangle $ which gives $\langle v^2 \rangle = 3 \langle v_x^2 \rangle $.  Your comment about generalization to n dimensions is also correct.

Comment: How do you write Latex here?

Comment: Use dollar signs $ around your code

Comment: So is it true that if $ \left \langle a^2 \right \rangle=\left \langle b^2 \right \rangle $, then $ a^2=b^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry to bother, but would this equation work if the squared signs were replaced by absolute value signs?

Comment: It's not true.  The averages of two quantities can be equal without the quantities being equal.  In your example above, clearly the x velocity and y velocity are two different physical quantities.  It just happens that their squares have the same average value when you look at many particles.

Comment: Then why is $\left \langle v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2 \right \rangle=\left \langle3 v_x^2 \right \rangle=3\left \langle v_x^2 \right \rangle $? I could see why$\left \langle v_x^2\right \rangle+\left \langle v_y^2\right \rangle+\left \langle v_z^2\right \rangle=3\left \langle v_x^2 \right \rangle $, but not how this leads to the first equality. I'm probably being very slow, apologies.

Comment: I'm having trouble with $\left \langle v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2 \right \rangle=\left \langle v_x^2\right \rangle+\left \langle v_y^2\right \rangle+\left \langle v_z^2\right \rangle$, essentially

Comment: @Alyosha: the expectation value is linear, so in general you have $\langle a + b \rangle = \langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle$.

Comment: Because they don't cancel? Thank you both!

Comment: Generally $\langle A + B \rangle = \langle A \rangle + \langle B \rangle$, this is more or less build into the setup. After all expectation values are computed by evaluating certain sums or integrals.